# SQL - Display Name ID from Consecutive Occurrences of values in a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table created, as an example 'Table1', see below;

```
Name    Year        
John    2003
Lyla    1994
Faith   1996
John    2002
Carol   2000
Carol   1999
John    2001
Carol   2002
Lyla    1996
Lyla    1997
Carol   2001
John    2009
```

Based on the above table, I have summarised my findings.

- Carol participated for 4 years in a row; 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002
- John participated for 3 years in a row; 2001, 2002, 2003 – John also participated in 2009, but this does not count as part of the streak.
- Lyla participated in 1994, 1996, 1997 but these were not three consecutive years.
- Faith participated only 1 time.

What I am looking to do is write a SQL query where only the Name Id in the table are displayed where the users have participated for 3 consecutive years or more, so I should only be getting the names of only 'Carol' and 'John' based on the above.

I am not exactly sure how to write this and would hope that someone could guide me.

I have only come up with a short and basic start like the one below, but in all honesty I am not sure that is even the correct way to go about it.

```
Select Name From Table1
Where Year = ?
Order by Name asc
Group by Year
```

Comment: If you have created the table as an example, then please also include the DDL and INSERT statements..

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have one row per person per year, you can use `lag()` and `select distinct`:

```
select distinct name
from (select t.*,
             lag(year, 2) over (partition by name order by name) as prev2_year
      from table1 t
     ) t
where prev2_year = year - 2;
```

This simply looks back two rows for each name and compares the year on that row to the year on the current row.  If there are three years in a row, then that year is exactly `year - 2`.

You could also do this with `join`s, but the above probably performs better:

```
select distinct t1.name
from table1 t1 join
     table1 t1_1
     on t1.name = t1_1.name and
        t1.year = t1_1.year + 1 join
     table1 t1_2
     on t1.name = t1_2.name and
        t1.year = t1_2.year + 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   n1.name,
   SUM(CASE WHEN n2.year is null then 0 else 1 end)+1 YearsInRow
from Table1 n1
left join Table1 n2 on n2.name=n1.name and (n2.year=n1.year+1 ) 
GROUP by n1.name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN n2.year is null then 0 else 1 end)+1 >=3
```

output:

```
name       YearsInRow
---------- -----------
Carol      4
John       3
```

Comment: I will also try the above as it looks like exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: @Luuk . . . Check to see what this does if there are gaps in the years.  I don't think it does what the OP intends.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: If i change the last `3` in a `2` (to find people with two consecutive years) the person named "Lyla" is also found, so i do not see the problem which you think exists.

Comment: @Luuk . . . This data does not have 3 years in a row:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4b0fc6d583acb404dd34ed0bda497358.

Comment: Ok , i added a (changed) query to you [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2298a7e8cccbe20233ac8b552f11f31b), conclusion, you solution is quicker an more readable... 